# Mysql Fulltext Index with AND condition accross multiple tables is slow

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have two huge tables (55M rows) with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `chapters` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `toc` varchar(5000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(5000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ari_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ari_id` (`ari_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `toc` (`toc`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `author` (`author`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52251463 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `ID` int(15) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `Author` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `isOpenAccess` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ari_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ari_id` (`ari_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Title` (`Title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Author` (`Author`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2627161 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I am using the following query for searching:

```
SELECT b.ari_id, b.Title, b.Author, t.toc, t.author
  FROM books b
 INNER JOIN chapters t
    ON b.ari_id = t.ari_id
 WHERE MATCH(t.toc) AGAINST('power*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
   AND b.isOpenaccess = 1 
 LIMIT 300
```

It is returning the results in about 12 seconds. Is there any chance that I can speed up the response time?

Second when I try to search from two fulltext indexes using "AND" operator, it takes forever to respond (146 seconds).  The query I am running is as follows:

```
SELECT toc, author
  FROM tocs
 WHERE MATCH(toc) AGAINST('high*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
   AND MATCH(author) AGAINST('max*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
 LIMIT 300
```

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY? what's the reason? *It is returning the results in about 12 seconds* How many time needs `SELECT ari_id FROM chapters WHERE MATCH(toc) AGAINST('power*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`? How many rows it returns? What is distinct `ari_id` amount? How many rows the whole query returns (w/o LIMIT)?

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY is faster as it does not involve sorting
"How many time needs.." depends upon how many users are querying
" How many rows it returns?" 300
"What is distinct ari_id amount?" 2.3M
"How many rows the whole query returns (w/o LIMIT)?" 53M

Answer (score 0):

In `books`, `ari_id` could be the `PRIMARY KEY` and you could get rid of `id`.  (This may or may not help performance.)

MySQL likes to run the `FULLTEXT` part of the `WHERE` first, *then* `AND` with the other tests.

This:

```
 WHERE MATCH(toc) AGAINST('high*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
   AND MATCH(author) AGAINST('max*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

can be sped up with `FULLTEXT(toc, author)` and

```
 WHERE MATCH(toc, author) AGAINST('high* max*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But it will find extra rows.  (Eg, the toc has both high and max, but author has neither.)

A similar trick is not possible when doing FT queries on each of two Joined tables.

OTOH, by having a 3rd table with all of columns, plus ari_id, would let you combine the tests into a single `MATCH`.  Then follow by further refinement.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I really appreciate it. However, as you have already mentioned "FULLTEXT(toc, author)" cannot be used as it will return unwanted rows as well.